# Start Cygwin process from Java

Tags: java, cygwin, octave

I need to use GNU Octave in a Windows environment. The Octave process will be called from Java server, using ProcessBuilder or Apache Commons Exec.

Octave needs to be run using Cygwin. What is the correct way to call Octave?

If I try to call octave directly from Windows (without Java)

```
cygstart octave-3.6.1.exe
```

I get error that a dll is missing (cygblas-0.dll). If I would start octave from cygwin shell (mintty.exe), it works. So one possible question is, is it possible to call octave outside cygwin shell by providing needed dlls?

Comment: It looks like your shell gets values from some startup scripts. You could call  bash -l -c /bin/ls

Comment: @Jayan I had managed to figure that much out, thanks!

Comment: is it necessary to use -i (interactive) option. If there is a specific reason, please include it in your answer..

Answer (score 2):

Are the DLL's in your PATH environment variable?  For instance my PATH includes c:\cygwin\bin and I can exec cygwin 'ls' command with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
new ProcessBuilder("c:/cygwin/bin/bash",
        "-l", // login
        "-i", // interactive
        "-c",
        "\"octave --help --interactive --no-line-editing\"");
```

works.